# javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

can anyone tell me about automatic cookies in JavaScript while clicking a button or URL of a webpage?
It sets for me and I can't delete that also...

```
 var expDate = new Date();
 expDate.setYear( parseInt(expDate.getYear())+10);
 document.cookie="";
var x = "$user=$val; expires="+expDate.toUTCString();
```

Here i have two buttons called 'view' and 'save'. If i click the 'save' button this cookie should be set... but when i click the 'view' button a cookie is set. i cant delete tht  cookie too

Comment: Please do some work then post the code if causing a problem. When you say automatic, when it happen? There are many events you can use with this. First you need to know how to set and delete cookies. Read some examples. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: First be sure that any cookies set by any website/application can be deleted by the user from his browser.. No body could restrict that.

Answer (score 0):

Best code to understand cookie in javascript

Just save my code as html file and open into browser you willeasily understand cookie concept

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getCookie(c_name)
 {
   var c_value = document.cookie;
   var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
   if (c_start == -1)
    {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
 if (c_start == -1)
   {
     c_value = null;
   }
 else
  {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
   if (c_end == -1)
     {
      c_end = c_value.length;
      }
   c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
   }
  return c_value;
  }

 function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

 function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```